# AWS SAM Local Lambda invocations slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, cold-start

I'm trying to test my lambda functions locally using the SAM local CLI.
I start the API with this command:

```
sam local start-api --template ./sam-template.yml --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4001
```

However, every time I call the API the lambda invocation takes a lot of time (4-5 seconds)
I assume the docker container is started every time a function is called.

Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add this argument to the SAM CLI command:

```
--warm-containers EAGER
```

So it would look like this:

```
sam local start-api  --warm-containers EAGER --template ./sam-template.yml --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4001
```

This prevents the containers that run the function from starting every time it is invoked by 'warming' them.

This was added from this feature request: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/239

Comment: is any flag for `sam local invoke`?

Comment: This works! My requests went from ~1500ms to about ~60ms. Thank you very much!